# Java Client - Server not repeat respond

Tags: java, sockets, client-server

//Edit 13:25
**Client Console**

```
Connect to server<br />
Repsonded: Tue May 22 13:23:28 CEST 2012<br />
Disconnect to server<br />
Connect to server<br />
Not run: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed<br />
Disconnect to server<br />
Connect to server<br />
Not run: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed<br />
Disconnect to server<br />
Connect to server<br />
Repsonded: Tue May 22 13:23:38 CEST 2012<br />
Disconnect to server<br />
Connect to server<br />
Not run: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed<br />
Disconnect to server<br />
Connect to server<br />
Not run: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed<br />
Disconnect to server<br />
Connect to server<br />
Not run: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed<br />
Disconnect to server<br />
Connect to server<br />
Not run: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed<br />
Disconnect to server<br />
Connect to server<br />
Not run: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed<br />
Disconnect to server<br />
Connect to server<br />
Not run: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed<br />
Disconnect to server<br />
Connect to server<br />
Not run: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed<br />
Disconnect to server<br />
Connect to server<br />
Not run: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed<br />
Disconnect to server<br />
Connect to server<br />
Not run: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed<br />
Disconnect to server<br />
Connect to server<br />
Not run: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed<br />
Disconnect to server<br />
```

**Server Console**

```
Server Initialized<br />
111111<br />
111111<br />
111111<br />
111111<br />
111111<br />
111111<br />
111111<br />
111111<br />
111111<br />
111111<br />
111111<br />
Error(run): java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error<br />


Server load data and not return repead "Repsonded: Tue May 22 13:23:38 CEST 2012" or client not ouput print.
```

Comment: Client error: Not run: java.net.SocketException: socket closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in your server implementation. You are not looping in the run statement, checking for new incomming messages from that connection. You read the information once and then close the connection in the finally statement:

```
 @Override
    public void run() {

        try {

            BufferedInputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            ...
        finally {
            try {
                connection.close();
```

Sure, your server has a loop checking for incomming connection requests, so this would work if the client tries to connect to the server again after each message is sent,  but your client only sends one request (in the beginning of the main statement).

So, what I would advice you to do:
Server-side, setup the streams etc in the `run` statement, and once they are set up enter a infinte loop with `while(true)`, and in that loop have the server read from the input stream, and if `read()` does not return null, print the message. This will cause the server check for incomming data from that client, once you get a string that's not null it will print it (and trigger a response if you want).

Same goes for client side, you need a loop that listens for incomming messages from the server

Comment: Please could you tell me to rewrite all the code? I have a salad with it already in my head. Trying to believe that long I would have figured it out but it would take a long time and I would have learned something more may not stand.

You can facilitate me to my very suffering :) If you have a little time so I'll be grateful.

Comment: You figured it out, great! It was not much modification which was needed but that can still be anoying if you don't know what to look for :)

Comment: It certainly was not difficult from your perspective, but I was not only well-meaning in PHP to Java and I jumped straight to the client <-> Server coding it up straight while I teach others and for my English, it also is great glory:-D . This took me to other problems but it is not easy.

Comment: Still makes me a problem to read data received from the server if Client.class imported into another class. I can not even using a static function to read the received data I could use globally.